# 'No Data Found' error and I don't understand why

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am receiving a issue with my code it is throwing me this error and I am unsure why because it doesn't make any sense If any of you guys could help me you'd be a life saver.

I have not really tried anything because I don't even know where to start to at least and try to fix this issue, I cannot find any inconsistencies in my code or anything at all and I am not sure why its pointing out theres no data in the declare section when in fact there is.

DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 7

`  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

```
DECLARE

v_newgoal donor.yrgoal%TYPE;
v_idno donor.idno%TYPE;
v_name donor.name%TYPE;
v_yrgoal donor.yrgoal%TYPE;

BEGIN

 SELECT idno, name, yrgoal
 INTO v_idno, v_name, v_yrgoal
 FROM donor
 WHERE v_idno = 11111;

 IF v_yrgoal > 500 THEN
  v_newgoal := v_yrgoal * 2;
 ELSIF v_yrgoal < 500 THEN
  v_newgoal := v_yrgoal + 250;
 ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('Error: Not Proceeding.');

 END IF;

 UPDATE donor
 SET yrgoal = v_newgoal
 WHERE idno = 11111;
 dbms_output.put_line(v_idno||' '||v_name||' '||v_yrgoal);

END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

`

Comment: Does `SELECT idno, name, yrgoal FROM donor  WHERE v_idno = 11111` return anything? You will get that "no data found" error if you are trying to use `SELECT INTO` with no data.

Comment: Also, are you sure that `v_idno = 11111` condition is correct? `v_idno` is not initialized, so I assume you actually want `WHERE idno = 11111`.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DECLARE
    v_newgoal donor.yrgoal%TYPE;    -- is Null
    v_idno donor.idno%TYPE;         -- is Null
    v_name donor.name%TYPE;         -- is Null
    v_yrgoal donor.yrgoal%TYPE;     -- is Null
BEGIN
    SELECT idno, name, yrgoal           -- >> NO_DATA_FOUND exception raised here
    INTO v_idno, v_name, v_yrgoal       -- Select ... INTO ... must return something
    FROM donor                          -- (when there is no row returned) >>> NO_DATA_FOUND  >>> could be handled in the EXCEPTION section below
            --WHERE v_idno = 11111;     -- this means "WHERE Null = 11111" - change the line to "WHERE idno = 11111"
    WHERE IDNO = 11111;                     

    IF v_yrgoal > 500 THEN
        v_newgoal := v_yrgoal * 2;
    ELSIF v_yrgoal < 500 THEN
        v_newgoal := v_yrgoal + 250;
    ELSE    -- if v_yrgoal is equal to 500 then v_newgoal will stay Null - don't think you want that
        dbms_output.put_line('Error: Not Proceeding.');  -- just message with no stopping --> UPDATE will be executed
    END IF;

    UPDATE donor
    SET yrgoal = v_newgoal  -- possible Null value
    WHERE idno = 11111;
    
    dbms_output.put_line(v_idno||' '||v_name||' '||v_yrgoal);
EXCEPTION                   -- EXCEPTION section - a place to handle different kinds of errors
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('some info about the ERR');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ... do something else ...
END;
```